# ggplot2 warning "removed x rows containing missing values" when drop = FALSE

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a side-by-side bar chart with ggplot2. My code produces the correct plot when `scale_x_discrete(drop = T)`. However, I have a level with a value of 0, and I want to include this on the x-axis. When I set `scale_x_discrete(drop = F)`, I get the warning: `Removed x rows containing missing values (geom_bar).` and another category with a non-zero value is shown as zero on the plot.

Here's a reprex of my data:

```
library("tidyverse")

df <- data.frame(
  location = c(rep("in", 231), rep("out", 83)),
  status = c(rep("normal", 73), rep("mild", 42), rep("moderate", 20), rep("fever", 4),
             rep("normal", 70), rep("mild", 41), rep("moderate", 62), rep("fever", 2)))

df$status <- factor(df$status, levels = c("normal", "mild", "moderate", "severe", "fever"))


df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = status,
             y = ..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.., sum)[..x..],
             fill = location)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F) +
  NULL
```

I have been looking at this for ages and really cannot work out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because even with `drop = FALSE` the missing categories are still not present in `..count..` and `..x..`. This can be seen by plotting `..count..` and `..x..`.

```r
library("tidyverse")

df <- data.frame(
  location = c(rep("in", 231), rep("out", 83)),
  status = c(rep("normal", 73), rep("mild", 42), rep("moderate", 20), rep("fever", 4),
             rep("normal", 70), rep("mild", 41), rep("moderate", 62), rep("fever", 2)))

df$status <- factor(df$status, levels = c("normal", "mild", "moderate", "severe", "fever"))
```

### Plot `..count..`

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = status,
             y = ..count..,
             fill = location)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F)
```

[image]

The missing categories are not present in `..count..` which we can infer from the fact that for `normal` only one value shows up, i.e. `..count..` is the vector

```r
..count.. <- c(143, 64, 19, 20, 62, 4, 2)
```

### Plot `..x..`

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = status,
             y = ..x..,
             fill = location)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F)
```

[image]

As with `..count..` the missing categories are not present in `..x..` i.e. `..x..` is the vector

```r
..x.. <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5)
```

### Why the code does not work

As a first step I compute `tapply(..count.., ..x.., sum)` which gives us a **vector of length 4** (total counts for non-missing status categories):

```r
tapply(..count.., ..x.., sum)
#>   1   2   3   5 
#> 143  83  82   6
```

Now, extracting the elements via `[..x..]` results in

```r
tapply(..count.., ..x.., sum)[..x..]
#>    1    2    2    3    3 <NA> <NA> 
#>  143   83   83   82   82   NA   NA
```

or

```r
..count.. / tapply(..count.., ..x.., sum)[..x..]
#>      1      2      2      3      3   <NA>   <NA> 
#> 1.0000 0.7711 0.2289 0.2439 0.7561     NA     NA
```

Hence your code results in two missings for the last two categories, which explains the warning `Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar)`. The reason is that with `..x.. <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5)` we are trying to extract two times the 5th element from the length 4 vector `tapply(..count.., ..x.., sum)` and therefore get NAs back.

In case of `drop=TRUE` everything works fine because in that case `..x.. <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)` while `..count..` is the same.

### Solution

The issue can be solved by converting `..x..` to a character vector. In that case we extract elements by names:

```r
library("tidyverse")

df <- data.frame(
  location = c(rep("in", 231), rep("out", 83)),
  status = c(rep("normal", 73), rep("mild", 42), rep("moderate", 20), rep("fever", 4),
             rep("normal", 70), rep("mild", 41), rep("moderate", 62), rep("fever", 2)))

df$status <- factor(df$status, levels = c("normal", "mild", "moderate", "severe", "fever"))

# Convert ..x.. to character
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = status,
             y = ..count.. / tapply(..count.., ..x.., sum)[as.character(..x..)],
             fill = location)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Can't explain the non-zero values not plotting.  Here is a solution using a dplyr's `group_by` functions

```
#calculate totals and then calculate the %
df %>% group_by(status, location) %>% summarise(value=n()) %>%   
  group_by(status) %>% mutate(result=value/sum(value)) %>%.      
  ggplot(aes(x = status,
             y = result,
             fill = location)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F)
```

Notice this now geom_col and not geom_bar.

[image]

Comment: That's a great work around, but still not 100% sure why I can't do this with `geom_bar`. I'll wait to see if someone else has an answer as to why my original code doesn't work before accepting your answer.